# How do I mention my spare time projects in resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, professionalism, job-search, new-job

What kind of heading/representation be good for mentioning my spare time projects. These projects I posted on github as mentioning "Spare time projects" heading sounds awkward to me although I googled some resume as well but unable to locate any good reference. One more thing is it ok to mention that part means I am not sure if it will be considered as a + point or a -ve one.

They are not very big (one wordpress plugin and a RoR project (for ref Rails is not my domain) so will it be ok to mention these under a proper heading or I will just eliminate it?

Let me know if someone needs more details to answer this :)

Comment: related: [Are independent projects appropriate to list on a resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17410/are-independent-projects-appropriate-to-list-on-a-resume)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Side Projects` or `Open Source Projects` would be a good heading.

If you expect hiring managers not to understand these are personal projects or projects you contribute to on your own time you should add a short paragraph before the listing explaining that, unless this is clear from the context of the listings.

An alternative is to have a single paragraph in your cover letter with a link to these projects.

Comment: Open Source Project heading sound g8 to me this time..but just a concern...i have only 2 projects in git repo .so is that ok to mention as projects are not very big and from my learning part(however the wordpress plugin is already been appproved by the community but yet it a very big plugin)

Comment: @swapnesh - No reason not to mention them, in particular if you are proud of them. They are more than most people can show.

Comment: Thanks for the words man :) Stack sites really helped me a lot..I started late (thats why I am not at good position :( ) but with stack sites I am learning day by day, something new and yes it bolster my confidence as well :)