# Should I include side project in resume?

Tags: professionalism, job-change

I am an IT guy, and in my company, I am just a normal, low ranking employee, and working on boring stuff every day.

However, at the same time, I am a founder of a very popular web site of its kind in the world (I am not exaggerating).

I would like to leave my company as soon as possible, but, the skill set and stuff I am doing at my company are not really marketable.

Therefore, I am thinking to post my side project on my resume, and the results I've achieved in a short period of time. My questions are:

1. Is it appropriate? Some people suggested not to do it, some people said go ahead.
2. If yes, how can I describe my role on that web site in my resume? as a volunteer, founder, CEO,CTO, etc?
3. Do side projects like this go on my LinkedIn profile?
4. I would like to show future employee what I can do, but at the same time I don't want my existing employee to know that I have such a good web site, and get fired.

Please don't ask me to tell my boss that I deserved something better. I've tried that, and it goes nowhere. I have done several things that have huge impact on company's revenue, but he ended up taking all the credit and climbing up the corporate ladder, while I continue to get buried under the hierarchy.

I am very depressed and need help from you guys! (By the way, although my web site is very popular, it still not able to generate enough income stream to support me and family, that's why I need a full time job and keep working on the web site).

Comment: Both these are relevant and related as well: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17410/2322 http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35413/2322

Comment: I'm interested to see what site this is, depending on its content and quality, it may change the responses.

Comment: re the possible duplicate votes: None of the other questions mention projects are particularly prestigious. If the OP's 'side' project is actually quite big, I'd argue that the answers to this question might be quite different to the answers for the proposed duplicates.

Comment: I also think that this isn't quite a duplicate. The main potential dupe is asking if the side project can help clear that first job hurdle, while this is more about self-marketing.

Comment: @yochannah did you check second question suggested by enderland? "we have an actual registered company and one paying client... it's been more than just a hobby venture... it's something I would like to be able to talk about at an interview"

Comment: See meta discussion [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2989/2322) on this question @yochannah.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate?

It depends on the site. If it's a porn site, or if you founded Pirate Bay, or if your site is highly political/religious then maybe not. But if it's something good/popular then yes - even if it's something entirely not "professional" like... the world's biggest Benedict Cumberbatch fansite.

> If yes, how can I describe my role on that web site in my resume?

Whatever your role is. Founder is fine. Webmaster is fine. CEO/etc are only fine if you have a corporate entity (and even then, I'd probably go with alternatives).

> Do side projects like this go on my LinkedIn profile?

If they go on your resume, they should go in LinkedIn.

> at the same time I don't want my existing employer to know that I have such a good web site, and get fired.

Eh? Why would an employer fire you over having a good website? The only way is if they think that you're slacking off on your job because of it (don't do that), or if your site is competitive and/or offensive (don't do that).