# Where to include part time Master project in Resume?

Tags: resume

I'm currently working full time as Senior Software Engineer. At the same time, I'm also taking a part time master degree on Software Engineering

The master degree requires a final year project and I ask my boss at the current company to propose a project for my final year project. So technically, this project is both school project and work project. In this project, I'm managing the team and using quite a number of technologies that I think will make resume look good

So in resume, where should I include this project experience? under current company job experience or in education section for master degree? I'm afraid if including this under education, the HR will not take it as a serious project. But I'm not sure anyone including master project as job experience?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effectively adding "Self-taught" skills on your Resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/effectively-adding-self-taught-skills-on-your-resume)

Comment: see also: [Should I include side project in resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36711/should-i-include-side-project-in-resume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project is relevant to the positions you are applying for, then you should include the project in your resume. Otherwise, no.

Having said that, I'd say you should include with project in your work experience since you also did it to fulfill a work requirement. It's probably not a good idea to clutter up your "Education" section if you can avoid it, as most HR's are only interested in whether you attended uni and whether you graduated therefrom and in fact, online applications are usually formatted to give you only the info they want: school, year of graduation and degree obtained - that's got to hurt if you went to Caltech and you have a string of hot projects to your credit. If you are in such a situation, you should create a separate section in your resumes where you can list your hot projects and published papers.