# Freelance work on resume along with full-time job

Tags: job-search, resume, fulltime, freelance

I'm currently working in an organization from past 2.5 years. I'm not really happy with current technology I'm working in. I always wanted to do something better and hence trained myself with another technology I liked using online resources and managed to get a freelance work on the same. I have been doing this freelance work from past 8 months and now I want to switch my fulltime job and work on this new technology that I'm currently working on as a freelancer.

I want to somehow showcase this skill on my resume more than what I'm doing in my current fulltime job. Can I put these freelance projects in resume? If yes, can they be mentioned as freelance projects or has to be put in a different way?

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: What would the different way be? You can't say they were projects for your full time employer.

Comment: Yes, that make sense. I certainly feel that there is no other way to showcase those skills. However, the concerning points are - current empoyer doesn't allow part time jobs and the companies I'm looking for may not like freelance projects put in the resume. Should I be worried about that?

Comment: @SaurabhKulkarni: Why would a future employer dislike freelance projects that show your skill? And how would your current employer ever find out after you've already switched jobs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I include side project in resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36711/should-i-include-side-project-in-resume)

Comment: Would you want to continue the freelance work alongside your putative new employment?

Answer (score 3):

When you work for an employer you are supposed to ensure them the amount of hours written in your contract, not the 24 hours of every day.

Therefore if you have also a freelancing activity that you do outside your working hours, mentioning it when applicable for the position  you are applying will be beneficial. Be sure to make clear what you did as employee and what you did as freelancer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can mention your freelance work on your resume.  And if it is at all relevant to positions you are applying to, you should mention it.  As someone who has been part of the interviewing process for software developers, I want to know the breadth and depth of your development experience.

On the resume, you can format it something like this:

#### Software Developer, DayjobCorp Inc., July 2018-present

- I developed internal solutions with technology ABC which (etc)

#### Software Developer (Freelance), April 2020-present

- Concurrent with working at DayjobCorp, I developed public-facing applications for customers on a freelance basis using technology XYZ which (etc)

Comment: I think it's good to subtly explain the overlapping dates like this, makes it clear that it's not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering from an Indian perspective.

I added my freelance experience in my resume too but did not have a good experience while interviewing. Everyone had their own excuse to not consider that tech stack.

I edited my resume and put it as a project or a part of the current project that I am working on with my current or previous company. No brows were raised then.

Also, if background checks worry you, most of the times, it is the tenure for which the candidate had worked that gets verified and not the project.

Go ahead and edit your resume.

Comment: This is assuming the freelance project can be related to your "normal" employer. Additionally I consider this a lie, that you can quickly get caught on "Doing ABC for this company? My friend works there, I know for sure they don't use this technology. If this candidate is lying on this, does they actually have any experience?"