# Is it a good idea to put my SE profile on my CV?

Tags: interviewing

It's advisable for people with little experience in the information technology (like myself) to mention their contribution to the IT world on their CVs, like helping with the development of an open-source software. I would love for person interviewing me to see my profile on SE InfoSec.

- Is it advisable to tell the world about your activities on SE?
- SE is a collection of different sites which means they will be able to see my activities on places other than SE InfoSec which reveals lots of details about my life style

Comment: Since there are two questions, the other question about including open source contributions also has many answers on SE already. Here's one example: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/adding-hobby-projects-to-resume

Comment: If you have a strong SE profile and that profile is relevant to the positions  category you are seeking, by all means provide a link to that SE profile in your CV. This is the age of social media - I have been told repeatedly at meetups that high tech startups go through candidates' social media profile, so a strong, positive social media footprint can only benefit you. It is unlikely at this point that you will succeed in sales, business development, marketing - in fact, any customer facing  activity, without a strong, positive social media footprint.

Comment: Let's put it this way, your Linkedin, Facebook, SE profiles tell me much more about you and how you can be valuable to me than your business card.

Comment: There was a time when I would have said no, it doesn't matter. But once my employer discovered my Stack Overflow profile, it became a big deal, and we worked to implement some initiatives to encourage our developers, testers, and others in the organization to contribute to asking and answering questions on the Stack Exchange network.  As part of our overall focus on continued learning, when they earn at least 500 rep on one of the sites, we give them prizes and points they can use to purchase stuff.